# Jquery - Featured Content Slider not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slider

Okay, so here is my problem.

I've been spending probably about 10 hours to try to put a Featured Content Slider on my website. Trying with anything I can come up with. Trying probably 3 different versions of the same slider.

The URL is: http://www.heartofphoto.com/slidetest/

But anyways, here is what I currently have going:

In the header I've managed to get this:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>try{jQuery.noConflict();}catch(e){};</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.3/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>
```

Having or not having the "noconflict" part doesn't really seem to make a difference. And I believe that the noconflict part came in after I installed the "google libary" plugin for Wordpress.

And here is the script that I have inside the page that should display the slider:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#featured").tabs({fx:{opacity: "toggle"}}).tabs("rotate", 5000, true);
});
</script>
```

Having that one in the "featured.php" file I made, or having it in the header.php file that is included at the top makes no difference.

So anyone have a clue what I am doing wrong?

Some edits:
I get error   SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support this property or method in slidetest, line 139 character 3.
Which is this line:

```
jQuery("#featured").tabs({fx:{opacity: "toggle"}}).tabs("rotate", 5000, true);
```

And for those of you that wanted to see my html. This version is actually using a php setup to get the data:

```
<div id="featured" >
      <ul class="ui-tabs-nav">
<?php
$postcount = 0;
$featured_query = new WP_Query('cat=29');
while ($featured_query->have_posts()) : $featured_query->the_post();
    get_the_ID();
    $postcount++;
?>
<?php
// get the image filename
$value_feat_img = get_post_custom_values("thumbnail");
if (isset($value_feat_img[0])) { ?>
        <li class="ui-tabs-nav-item ui-tabs-selected" id="nav-fragment-<?php echo $postcount; ?>"><a href="#fragment-<?php echo $postcount; ?>">

        <img src="<?php echo bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/thumb.php?src=<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "thumbnail", $single = true); ?>&amp;h=50&amp;w=80&amp;zc=1&amp;q=95" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" /><span><?php the_title(); ?></span></a><?php } ?>
</li>
          <?php endwhile; ?>

      </ul>

<?php
$postcount = 0;
$featured_query = new WP_Query('cat=29');
while ($featured_query->have_posts()) : $featured_query->the_post();
    get_the_ID();
$postcount++;
?>

    <!-- Content -->
    <div id="fragment-<?php echo $postcount; ?>" class="ui-tabs-panel" style="">
    <?php   // get the image filename
                        $value_img = get_post_custom_values("thumbnail");

if (isset($value_img[0])) { ?>            

        <img src="<?php echo bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/thumb.php?src=<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "thumbnail", $single = true); ?>&amp;h=300&amp;w=390&amp;zc=1&amp;q=95" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />

        <?php } ?>
         <div class="info" >

            <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" ><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
         </div>
    </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>

</div>
```

Comment: Are there any errors in your console?

Comment: What does your html look like?

Comment: I get this "SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support this property or method" at slidetest, line 139 character 3.

Wich is the 
jQuery("#featured").tabs({fx:{opacity: "toggle"}}).tabs("rotate", 5000, true);
row

Answer (score 0):

May be a stupid question, but, are all those spaces in the google library call actually there in your code? IE

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2    /jquery.min.js'></script>
```

I ask because that's not a valid reference to jQuery so it doesn't matter if there's a conflict or not, jQuery won't be defined.

Comment: That is weird because when I look at my page I won't see that. And I'm actually using a wordpress function to load the library. (wp_enqueue_script)

Comment: I now realized that I had accidentally managed to add it when writing my post. And nope, it shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 0):

Seems the original creator of the theme had put an old version off jQuery in a clumsy way in the footer.

Removing that got my slider to start working.